# PHP - Reverse associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get the value of the index that it's associated with.

Let's say  I have an `'fname' => 'Bear'` *Then I receive a recieve an input from the user with a value of* `'Bear'` **I want to Identify the data through the use of association**, is it possible to build an array that looks like this `'fname' <=> 'Bear` ? If yes, can you give me some example on how to use it?

this is my PHP code

```
$array = array('lname'=>'Teddy', 'fname' => 'Bear'); 

 $user_input = 'Teddy';
 echo $array[$user_input]; // I want this to give me the value of lname
                           // because lname is associated with Teddy
```

Comment: [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)?

Comment: Or [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php): `echo array_keys($array, $user_input)[0];` [See demo](https://eval.in/426884)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to use [`array_flip`](http://php.net/array_flip)

```
$array = array('lname'=>'Teddy', 'fname' => 'Bear');

$user_input = "Teddy";

$flipped = array_flip($array);

echo $flipped[$user_input]; // lname
```

Comment: Cool. Never heard of it. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest one is using `array_search` as

```
echo array_search('Teddy',$array); // lname
```

Comment: This is much more efficient as it does not require you to copy the array like in my answer.

Comment: Yes it is but none less yours one is an alternative to the answer. @phpisuber01